# Errbot Natural Language Processing

Tags: python, nlp, errbot

I would like to add some basic Natural Language Processing or Natural Language understanding into a bot I have implemented with the errbot library. This is to add in basic conversation to the bot. So that the operator can have some basic chat with the chatbot. Perhaps leveraging NTLK.

Is this something anyone has done already or has any god pointers?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use some pre-trained models that will have related functionalities
such as:

- https://rasa.com/docs/get_started_step1/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-luis?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs
- https://github.com/etalab/cowbots